# Issues panel not showing errors

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have problem with my QT Creator. I recently update my QT Creator to 4.1.0 version (based on Qt 5.7.0 ) and when I compile simple "hello world" with intentionally error within, it doesn't show any error in Issues panel (its completely empty). Program isn't compiling and error is showing in the "Compile Output" panel but not in the Issues. In the QT Creator 2.5.2 (based on QT 4.8.2) it work perfectly fine (error is showing in the both panels). I tried almost everything and I still don't know why this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out. I need to force update CMake from 2.8 to newest version and it work fine. Here's instruction how to do it: 
[LINK](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/611/installing-cmake-3.4.1-ubuntu-14.04-trusty-using-alternatives)